# Django rest AllAuth: ImportError at /auth/registration/ No module named account.adapter

Tags: python, django, rest, django-allauth

I'm trying to make a custom adapter to edit the send_mail function in allauth.account.adapter (following this instructions http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-redirects), but when I execute the function It can't find the account module. This is the traceback:

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/auth/registration/

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'api',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework_swagger',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'rest_auth',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'rest_auth.registration',
 'djrill')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  456.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  453.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_auth/registration/views.py" in post
  43.         if self.form.is_valid():
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  184.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  176.             self.full_clean()
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  392.         self._clean_fields()
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
  410.                     value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py" in clean_username
  252.         value = get_adapter().clean_username(value)
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/adapter.py" in get_adapter
  359.     return import_attribute(app_settings.ADAPTER)()
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/utils.py" in import_attribute
  119.     ret = getattr(importlib.import_module(pkg), attr)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/lccot/Documents/cursoslccbackend/cursoslccbackend/cursoslccbackend/adapters/allauth.py" in <module>
  2. from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

Exception Type: ImportError at /auth/registration/
Exception Value: No module named account.adapter
```

This is the custom adapter file (allauth.py):

```
from django.conf import settings
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class CustomAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def send_mail(self, template_prefix, email, context):
        msg = self.render_mail(template_prefix, email, context)
        msg.send()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the name of the custom adapter file. It's named "allauth.py". Just rename the file to something else.

This happens because the python module import search work in this order:

- the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
- PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the
- shell variable PATH). the installation-dependent default.